# Creating a ControlTemplate at Runtime in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, runtime, controltemplate

I'm writing a Silverlight application that requires me to dynamically create a ControlTemplate at runtime.  Most of the solutions I've found involve creating a new template for each case, but I have far too many cases to do this.  How would I create a new ControlTemplate in C#?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create a ControlTemplate in Silverlight in C# alone. Unlike WPF (where you can set the [VisualTree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.visualtree.aspx) property), there is no property you can set that specifies the "content" of the ControlTemplate.

You can define your XAML as a string, and then load that dynamically in C# as explained by this [blog post](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/08/05/tip-of-the-day-24-how-to-apply-a-xaml-template-to-a-class.aspx).

The code boils down to:

```
var template = (ControlTemplate)XamlReader.Load("<ControlTemplate " +                 
       " xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"" +
       " xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\">" +
       " content here " +
       "</ControlTemplate>");
```